# Laravel Get File Contents of Image but Not Working on Production Environment

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, centos7

My code bellow working on localhost development

```
<img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ url('image?type=user&file='.Auth::user()->picture_file.'&mime='.Auth::user()->picture_mime) }}" alt="Image Description">
```

will access `imageController` with `get` method using this link `image?type=user&file=USER000053.png&mime=image/png`

```
class ImageController extends BaseController
{
    public function get(Request $request){
        $file=Storage::disk($request->type)->get($request->file); 
        return response($file,200)->header('content-Type',$request->mime);
    }
}
```

bellow my `filesystem.php` config file

```
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/user'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

that code above works well on localhost. but when we tried to push to production server (centos os), that code won't works. Its just returning a damage image.

we have tried

1. [check] make sure storage and temp accessible. chmod 755. even we have tried 777
2. [check] `chown` to user apache.apache
3. [check] set selinux permisive mode
4. [check] we have make sure that file already exists

   ```
   $file_exists = Storage::disk($request->type)->exists($request->file);
   ```

   the code above return true
5. [check] trying this code bellow

   ```
   $response = Response::make($file, 200);
   $response->header('Content-Type', $request->mime);
   return $response;
   ```

   still won't work
6. trying to make symlink

   ```
   php artisan storage:link
   ```

   its makes symlink on `public` folder but still won't work
7. trying to download and still doesn't works

   ```
    return response()->download(storage_path('app/' . $request->type . "/" . $request->file));
   ```

I'm running on Centos 7 Environment at GCP. any idea would be help me. thank you

**update 1**
Here are the result from our server

[image]

**update 2** 
I have already check for that image on server and its fine and could be read

**update 3**

We have do this

```
$img = file_get_contents(public_path("storage/user/" . $request->file));
return response($img)->header('Content-type','image/png');
```

still not working

**update 4** 
we make our own symbolic link on `public folder` as bellow
storage -> /var/www/html/*****/storage/app/

still not working

**update 5** 
I have directly accessing file through browser, it comes up with the picture.

**update 6** 
Have already set `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local` or `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=user`on env file and still doesn't works

**update 7**

filesystem.php

```
 'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'calculate_disk' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/calculate'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/user'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'invoice' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/invoice'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/image', 'ImageController@get');
```

update 8

after digging a while of `FileSystemDriver` I was curious about bellow `url` value that linked to `localhost` instead of our url. any idea?

```
FilesystemAdapter {#479 ▼
  #driver: Filesystem {#482 ▼
    #adapter: Local {#475 ▼
      #pathSeparator: "/"
      #permissionMap: array:2 [▼
        "file" => array:2 [▼
          "public" => 420
          "private" => 384
        ]
        "dir" => array:2 [▼
          "public" => 493
          "private" => 448
        ]
      ]
      #writeFlags: 2
      -linkHandling: 2
      #pathPrefix: "/var/www/html/***/storage/app/user/"
    }
    #plugins: []
    #config: Config {#477 ▼
      #settings: array:2 [▼
        "url" => "http://localhost/storage"
        "visibility" => "public"
      ]
      #fallback: null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to access the image endpoint outside the app or did you try everything checking directly in your app?

Comment: Yes, we did. we have directly accessing endpoint

Comment: what output(url) does `{{ url('image?type=user&file='.Auth::user()->picture_file.'&mime='.Auth::user()->picture_mime) }}` gives in browser?

Comment: @ab.in `src="http://x.x.x.x/image?type=user&file=USER000053.png&mime=image/png"`

Comment: So just to check, is your `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` variable in the `.env` file `user`?

Comment: can you show the particular `get` route for `/image`?

Comment: @sebasaenz yup `'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),`

Comment: @ab.in did you mean request link ? `image?type=user&file=USER000053.png&mime=image/png`

Comment: @YohanesAI I meant the value for `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER`, that is in your `.env` file

Comment: If that is not set you should set it to `user`

Comment: @sebasaenz did u mean 
user' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/user'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: @YohanesAI I mean the the `route` like `Route::get('/image', 'ImageController@get')`

Comment: @sebasaenz we have already set it

Comment: @ab.in sorry my mistake. here you go `Route::get('/image', 'ImageController@get');`

Comment: No, your `.env` file, is the variable `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` set in your `.env` file?

Comment: @sebasaenz sorry not notice it. we don't set any particular `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` on env file. should we set it?

Comment: @sebasaenz we don't set too at our localhost and its working

Comment: It might be worked in local because `'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),` have a default value `local` if `env` is not set.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `ob_get_clean();` before response file. 
It will clean all buffers and return content to display image.

Comment: Had similar issue , nice answer

Comment: this also helps with any route that has debugbar enabled, but shouldn't... like QR codes and PDFs

Answer (score 0):

If command `ob_get_clean();` helps you, check your code on extra whitespaces before `__<?php` .